# How to recover files from a DVD with command line method?

Tags: data-recovery

I do not see my DVD, I do not know how to access its corrupted data.
What is the way to recover the data with command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>from [this source](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/foremost)</sub>

---

1. get the path of your DVD with `blkid`

   ```
   #example:
   blkid
   /dev/sda1: UUID="4ea68146-163e-4ce6-aeda-4cc2d338c2ed" TYPE="ext4" 
   /dev/sdb1: UUID="e1977a53-b9f4-4c96-9251-84af259d06b4" TYPE="swap" 
   /dev/sdb5: UUID="a85b1b95-c5ce-4557-9ca4-503b1a9ddcc8" TYPE="ext4" 
   /dev/sdb6: UUID="c71a7601-04b8-4808-8f7b-ec967ac967ba" TYPE="ext4" 
   /dev/sr0: LABEL="Disc" TYPE="udf"
   ```

   `sda`and `sdb`are Hard Disk. `/dev/sr0` is the DVD

---

2. then to acces the DVD content, use `foremost` 
   (Install it with `sudo apt-get install foremost`)

   List the content of the DVD (even the erased one):

   ```
   sudo foremost -w /dev/sr0
   Processing: /dev/sr0
   |********************************************|
   ```

   Result is available with:

   ```
   sudo cat ~/output/audit.txt | more

   Foremost version 1.5.7 by Jesse Kornblum, Kris Kendall, and Nick Mikus
   Audit File

   Foremost started at Tue Jun 14 23:25:18 2016
   Invocation: foremost -w /dev/sr0 
   Output directory: /home/yourlogon/output
   Configuration file: /etc/foremost.conf
   ------------------------------------------------------------------
   File: /dev/sr0
   Start: Tue Jun 14 23:25:18 2016
   Length: 4 GB (4573593600 bytes)

   Num  Name (bs=512)         Size  File Offset     Comment 

   0:        1152.jpg         2 MB          589824      
   1:        7168.jpg         2 MB         3670016      
   2:       13292.jpg         2 MB         6805504      
   3:       19368.jpg         2 MB         9916416      
   4:       24808.jpg         2 MB        12701696      
   5:       30464.jpg         2 MB        15597568      
   6:       35132.jpg         2 MB        17987584      
   7:       40868.jpg         2 MB        20924416      
   8:       46916.jpg         2 MB        24020992
   ...
   ```

---

3. To recover all data

   ```
   sudo foremost all /dev/sr0
   Processing: /dev/sr0
   |********************************************|
   ```

   everything is then available in `~/output/`

---

4. And to make files available `sudo chmod -R 777 ~/output/`

Comment: Foremost is a file carver, it should be used as a last resort when the file system is not available. Was this the scenario? I.e. file system corruption?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto,  In this case: a friend tried to re-write on the DVD, and his data get corrupted, he could not access his data anymore (on Windows). Loading his DVD, I couldn't see any data too on Ubuntu, so I tried for this process of recovery and it worked.

Comment: OK but my doubt is... Why not trying with the standard tools like Testdisk first? :-) I am just curious. If the scenario was that of deep corruption maybe it should be stated in the answer.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto , i don't know `testdisk`. Fill free to edit the answer to improve it, or propose your answer to share.